# Cannot close stream until all bytes are written aws s3 upload image

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am using below code

```
using (AmazonS3Client s3client = 
          new AmazonS3Client( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3accesskey"], 
                              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3secret"]))
{
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = rootBucket,
        Key = key,
        InputStream = content
    };

    s3client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);
```

It is throwing below error

> Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.

please advise

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the stream is at the end. Just set the position of your stream back to 0 and it'll work.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

it seems you can also get this same exception intermittently when S3 times out while uploading. you can fix that by increasing the timeout, e.g.:

```
new AmazonS3Client( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3accesskey"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s3secret"],
                    new AmazonS3Config { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                                         ReadWriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) } )
```